# Estou a tentar usar uma função assincrona em python-3, mas esta a dar erro

Tags: python, python-3.x, async

**Erro:**

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\tiago.pereira\Desktop\python\kivy\kivy_teste.py", line 43
    pythoncom.PumpMessages()
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Keyboard' was never awaited
TypeError: an integer is required (got type coroutine)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tiago.pereira\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pyHook\HookManager.py", line 348, in KeyboardSwitch
    event = KeyboardEvent(msg, vk_code, scan_code, ascii, flags, time, hwnd, win_name)
SystemError: <class 'pyHook.HookManager.KeyboardEvent'> returned a result with an error set
```

**Codigo:**

```
import pythoncom,pyHook
import threading
import ctypes,sys,asyncio
import cv2
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *


#kivy.require('1.9.0')



#def popup():
 #   popup = Popup(content=Label(text="I am popup"))s
  #  popup.open()

first = True

async def Keyboard(event):    
    print(event.GetKey())


    if event.GetKey() == 'Lcontrol':
        ctypes.windll.user32.LockWorkStation()
    elif event.GetKey() == 'Next': 
        sys.exit(0)
    else:
        await picture
        return False

async def picture():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)    
    ret,frame = cap.read()  # return a single frame in variable `frame`
    cv2.imwrite('C:/Users/tiago.pereira/desktop/c1.png',frame)    
    cap.release()    


hm = pyHook.HookManager()
hm.KeyDown = Keyboard
#hm.MouseAll = Mouse
hm.HookKeyboard()
#hm.HookMouse()
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

Comment: E o `HookManager.KeyDown` suporta uma função `async`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3673769/pyhook-pythoncom-stop-working-after-too-much-keys-pressed-python pelo que li sim

Comment: Não vi onde essa pergunta cita sobre corotinas (async). Ali utiliza-se thread, que é um conceito completamente diferente. Recomendo que reveja a documentação do módulo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei a solução:

```
t = threading.Thread(target=picture) #added to queue
t.start()
```

Comment: Olá @Tiago. Marque a sua resposta como válida!

Comment: Sim, como eu expliqueii - você não tem que usar asyncio. Código multi-threaded não exige nenhuma mudança nas funções, apenas alguns cuidados pra não alterar a mesma estrutura de dados em paralelo - e nesse caso não há o risco de se ter muitas threads rodando ao mesmo tempo. (em um código de servidor a recomendação é ter um threadpool, e aí fica um pouco mais complexo)

Answer (score 3):

Em particular, a pergunta que você citou nos comentários é de 2010 - o async do Python como é hoje nem existia ainda (nem a sintaxe, nem o conceito). Certamente esse módulo não suporta funções assíncronas.

A solução óbvia aí é simplesmente fazer da sua função keyboard uma função normal, sem ser assíncrona. A única coisa assíncrona que ela faz está na verdade na outra função - `picture`

que aliás, está chamada de forma errada - deveria ser `await picture()`. E ai SE o framework do  PythonHook funcionasse de com o AsyncIO do Python, a própria função `Keyboard` seria suspensa até a `picture` estar pronta. Dificilmente parece ser o que você realmente quer.

O que você gostaria aí é - independente de Keyboard  poder ser assíncrona ou não - é processar a tecla pressionada o mais rápido possível, se alguma das teclas tiver um processo longo, ai você dispara isso como uma tarefa assíncrona separada - e encerra a função Keyboard, ficando "pronto pra próxima tecla". Ou seja: a função Keyboard não precisa ser assíncrona - ela precisa criar tarefas baseadas nas teclas pressionadas.

A forma de criar uma nova tarefa assíncrona é com o método `create_task` do loop de eventos. (é nova em Python 3.7. Em 3.5 e 3.6 ela não existia e deve-se usar o `ensure_future`).

Mesmo numa função assíncrona, se você não precisa do valor de retorno de outra função assíncrona no ponto em que você está no código, deve-se usar o `create_task`, em vez do `await`. O `await` faz a **sua** função esperar a outra ser completada. todo o mecanismo de async do Python faz com que outras tarefas e funções possam continuar executando, mas a função que tem o `await` fica pausada esperando a resposta da sub-tarefa, da mesmíssima forma que em código síncrono.

Ou seja, o seu código vai funcionar - pelo menos essa parte, se a sua função de keyboard for escrita como:

```
def Keyboard(event):    
    print(event.GetKey())


    if event.GetKey() == 'Lcontrol':
        ctypes.windll.user32.LockWorkStation()
    elif event.GetKey() == 'Next': 
        sys.exit(0)
    else:
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        loop.create_task(picture())
    return False  # Fora do "if": também retorna False quando o sistema sair do "LockWorkStation" acima

async def picture():
   ...
```

Claro, que para isso funcionar vai depender do resto do código iniciar um event-loop do asyncio que esteja funcionando normalmente - não é o default do kiwi funcionar com asyncio.

Comment: Obg penso que tmb seria uma opção viavel